# How to create private non-primitive $scope variables inside nested scope like ng-switch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html template:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberList">
    <ng-switch on="editMode">                           

         <span ng-switch-when="false"> 
             some html
         </span>

        <span ng-switch-when="true">
          <form role="form" ng-init="setFormModel($parent.$index)">
          <form-element ng-model="formModel.name"></form-element>
          <form-element ng-model="formModel.address"></form-element>                   
          <form-element ng-model="formModel.id"></form-element>
        </span>

</ng-switch>
</div>
```

Inside Controller I have the setFormModel method as

```
$scope.setFormModel=function(index){
    $scope.formModel={
        name        :$scope.memberList[index].name,
        address     :$scope.memberList[index].address,
        id          :$scope.memberList[index].id,
    };
};
```

Now, It is required that each member-form has its own copy of `formModel` so that individual member forms are independent of each other.With the current method `setFormModel()`, changes in one member form reflects in all other forms,as if they share the same model and the same copy of $scope.formModel is available to all the forms.How can I create seperate models for each form? or what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each `member`. You can just do `<form-element ng-model="member.name"></form-element>`

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberList">
  <form role="form">
     <form-element ng-model="member.name"></form-element>
     <form-element ng-model="member.address"></form-element>                   
     <form-element ng-model="member.id"></form-element>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Modified the example to have master/clone copies:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in memberList" ng-init="cloned = copy(member)>
  <form role="form">
     <form-element ng-model="cloned.name"></form-element>
     <form-element ng-model="cloned.address"></form-element>                   
     <form-element ng-model="cloned.id"></form-element>
     <button type="submit" ng-click="member = copy(cloned)">save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This requires the to be a function `copy` on the scope. You can define it on the controller:

```
function copy(item){
   return angular.copy(item);
}
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3ZyiAqAhufUQCQ8Csq7?p=preview)

Comment: I can not make direct changes in `member` until the form has been submitted, so I need to do it in a different object.Otherwise, the unsubmitted changes reflect in my original model, whereas they are required to be discarded when user has not submitted them.

Comment: @Abdul23 you could make a [deep copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) of the original and work from there.

Comment: @Yoshi, this is exactly what I had in mind - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3ZyiAqAhufUQCQ8Csq7?p=preview), except I couldn't make `angular.copy` work from within `ng-init` - had to create a function on the scope instead

Comment: +1 Though is it really necessary to work on individual copies? I would just copy the whole array inside the controller and use that copy in the view. On submit one could then merge or reset or similar.

Comment: @Yoshi, I would also treat ViewModel separate from the Model, and make explicit commits, but this seemed more aligned with the OPs approach.

Comment: Using a copy of member is the way to go.Since I am new to angular, I wanted to explore (with the approach I used)if there is a possibility with angular of creating new scope variables inside methods which are defined on the scope from which the method is called.I guess there is no direct way of doing so or I need to explore a little more.Thanks for your help.